# Nesting a second $.when() inside done()

Tags: jquery, getscript

"Is it possible to nest a second $.when().done() inside of another $.when().done(). It seems to work sometimes but not consistently. The problem seems to be that the second done() does not always fire. I included a sample of what I am trying to do below.

```
$.when(
    // config file
    $.getScript("config.js")
).done(function(){
    $.when(
        // load js files
        $.getScript("file1.js"),
        $.getScript("file2.js"),
        $.getScript("file3.js"),
        $.getScript("file4.js"),
        $.getScript("file5.js"),
        $.getScript("file6.js")
    ).done(function(){
        console.log("done")
    });
});
```

Comment: it should work fine.... try adding an error handler to the second when to see what error has occurred

Comment: Thanks Arun! I dont know why i didnt think of that. It appears that one file (blueimp/jQuery.fileupload.js) intermittently fails to load. It shows the entire plugin file as the repsonseText.

Comment: Problem solved. It turns out that particular plugin file is dependent upon a second file also being loaded in the second when. I placed the dependent file into the first when and it works every time now.